# Accessing SQL server DB of my local server over internet

Tags: sql, sql-server

My client is using my SQL Sever application, sever installed on one of his local computers, dbs are being accessed using

```
 connectionString="Data Source=Office1-MAIN-PC\EziBilling;Initial Catalog=dbBilling;User ID=sa"
```

By now everything is fine, now he demands to access the databases attached to local server, through internet too.
I am planning to create a client application that could connect to the server instance over internet.  BUT I do not know what connection string I should use.

Also, how can I get the IP address of the server (do not have static IP)?

Thanks

Comment: don't do that, use a vpn or a webservice/WCF as a middle layer. SQL Server on the internet mean that when (not if) the next Nimda or Code Red go wild the data of your customer will be available to everyone. security issues happen but some can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1433 is the port, in this example. 
The port must be free on the firewall, and you need to enable port forwarding (TCP) in the router, and SQL server must allow remote connections (and be enabled for the TCP protocol)

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```